# What is this anime or manga about "Leben Nicht"?

Tags: identification-request

I'm not sure what it is or what it's called. The title seems to be in Russian but that got me nowhere... All it says is "Leben Nicht" at the top followed by "168cm" and "47kg".

[image]

It shows a girl with white hair next to a girl who I guess is her except the white-haired version almost looks like she went through a Frankenstein surgery with her skin having scars and such. It looked interesting to me but I can't find it anywhere. It had Japanese writing but I don't read Japanese.

Does anyone know what this anime or manga is?

Comment: Do you have an image of it? It'll be a lot easier for us to figure out what the series is if you do.

Comment: http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8e/20/5c/8e205cd6bb25abd036196e38859e9705.jpg

Comment: sorry im having trouble posting the picture

Comment: the above url should take you to the picture

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be an original character by artist 浦助 (Urasuke), sometimes known by other names such as "ursk420" or "tetsu420". It was [posted to his pixiv account](http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=31105139) roughly a year ago (standard disclaimer: Pixiv links are **not guaranteed to be work-safe** since the content is dynamically generated). The character's name is Leben Nicht (German meaning roughly "not alive"). The caption for the picture and the tag "オリジナル" ("original", used when a character is not part of any series) both indicate that there isn't any anime or manga about the character, so unfortunately it seems you're out of luck on that end. However, the picture was released such a way as to allow essentially unlimited derivative works, so you may be able to find more images of this character.

I don't think this artist has been involved in any other professional manga or anime to date, though it's hard to tell. At the very least I couldn't find references to any such works after skimming [his pixiv page](http://www.pixiv.net/member.php?id=98263), [blog](http://tr0mb000rn.jugem.jp/), [interview page](http://theinterviews.jp/gnsk_uraki420) and [twitter](https://twitter.com/ursk420). He does have a sizable following online, but according to his pixiv profile he mostly draws original characters.

Comment: wow... I really wasn't expecting an answer, thank you very much haha. I had found this picture on a website for artists and saw this thinking it may be part of a larger series. But if all this person seems to do at the moment is original characters then hes got a great imagination and stunning work,its kind of a let down because the girl would seem to have potential in a darker-set story and filled with personality. But thans Logan M for researching that so thoroughly!

Comment: @MerrickDuBois You're welcome, and for what it's worth I agree that this artist has a lot of cool artwork which would make neat concepts for anime/manga. If you found this answer helpful, you might consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it. Once you get 15 rep you can also upvote any questions and answers. We generally give pretty well-researched and thorough answers here, and you're welcome to stick around (^.^).